# Reversing a Linked List not working in C. Only giving the top element

Tags: c

I tried reversing a linked list using the following code but only the first element of the unreversed linked list is been shown in the print.

Please help.

The output is:

```
Element: 7
Element: 11
Element: 66
------------------
Element: 7
```

The elements before dashes are unreversed and below are reversed with is not happenning.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void LinkedListTraversal(struct Node *ptr)
{
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("Element: %d\n", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

struct Node *Reverse(struct Node *head)
{
    Node *cur = head;
    Node *prev = NULL;
    Node *temp;
    // temp;
    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        /* code */
        temp = cur->next;
        cur->next = prev;
        prev= cur;
        // cout<<prev->next<<endl;
        cur = temp;

    }
    head =  prev;
    return head;
}

int main()
{

    // Creation of Linked List
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *second;
    struct Node *third;

    head = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    second = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    third = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    head->data = 7;
    head->next = second;

    second->data = 11;
    second->next = third;

    third->data = 66;
    third->next = NULL;

    LinkedListTraversal(head);
    Reverse(head);
    cout << "------------------\n";
    LinkedListTraversal(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whenever you have problems with things like linked lists, my recommendation is that you use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement, while simultaneously use pencil and paper to visualize the lists and the operations you perform on them. For example with a simple list, draw it as a series of squares, linked together with arrows (the arrows represents the links, or pointers in general). When you perform an operation which modifies a pointer, you erase and redraw the corresponding arrow on the paper.

Comment: Which value does `prev` have when this is executed the first time: `cur->next = prev;`?

Comment: `cur->next = prev` This statement breaks the initial connection and `cur` node will point the previous node. That's how the linked list will be reversed. At first, `prev` is assigned to `NULL`. So at first, the `cur` node will point to null.

Comment: `head = Reverse(head);` just that. Don't mix `C` & `C++`, it's annoying.

Comment: While much of your code could be considered simple C, it's actually C++. So your tag and your title is wrong. And whatever resource you're using to learn C (or C++?) is probably not a very good one. What are you trying to learn, C or C++?

Comment: @Bodo Thanks for pointing out my mistake. My edited answer sounds pretty similar to before, but is subtly different and now is no additional insight to existing answers.... So I keep it deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Reverse` function works perfectly well.

Your will laugh, because your mistake is really silly : you use the wrong parameter for your function.
Now that your list is reversed, `head` is the new tail and it points to `NULL`.

Call your function like that :

```
LinkedListTraversal(head);
Reverse(head);
cout << "------------------\n";
LinkedListTraversal(third);
```

Comment: Function `Reverse` is already designed to return the new value of `head`, but the code in the question ignores the return value.

Comment: Needing to know the former last element of a linked list in order to output the reversed list seems awkward. Why did you reject  the idea to use the returned new head, which points there? E.g. `LinkedListTraversal(Reverse(head));` or as in the other answer `head = Reverse(head);`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list like `7 -> 11 -> 66` where `head` points to `7`. Then you reverse the list to `66 -> 11 -> 7`. The new `head` should point to `66`. Your code prints the list from the unmodified `head` which still points to `7`.

Your function `Reverse` is designed to return the new list head, but you ignore the return value. Use

```
head = Reverse(head);
```

to get the new head in your `main` function.

Maybe you thought that `Reverse` would modify the `head` value in `main`. This is not true. The function modifies a local copy of the pointer only. That's why it returns the new value. If you would design `Reverse` to take  the address of the `head` pointer, it could modify the pointer in `main`.

Alternative solution:

```
/* modified lines marked with comments ***** */
struct Node *Reverse(struct Node **head)
{
    Node *cur = *head;  /*****/
    Node *prev = NULL;
    Node *temp;
    // temp;
    while (cur != NULL)
    {
        /* code */
        temp = cur->next;
        cur->next = prev;
        prev= cur;
        // cout<<prev->next<<endl;
        cur = temp;

    }
    *head =  prev; /*****/
}


/* and to pass the address of the head pointer, call it like */
Reverse(&head);
```